# JS match string from right to left

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following object:

```
const obj = {
  'myApi': ['keyOne', 'keyTwo'],
  'myApi.keyOne': ['three', 'four'],
  'myApi.keyTwo': [...],
  'myApi.keyOne.three': [...]
  'myApi.keyOne.four': [...]
}
```

Now, based on the following string:

```
const str = "if(myApi.keyOne.three"
```

I want to match the correct object key, but from **right to left**. So, in the above example, I want to get `obj["myApi.keyOne.three"]`.

`indexOf` or `str.test` methods will not work because they will catch `myApi` and `myApi.keyOne` also.

Note that it could be any string, the `str` is just an example. For example:

```
while(myApi.keyOne.three) {} // should match obj["myApi.keyOne.three"]
if(myApi.keyOne) {} // should match obj["myApi.keyOne"]
```

etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: Just slice off the `if(` portion, and then use bracket notation? Or am I missing something?

Comment: it's dynamic, I will add this in the question

Comment: If it could really be *any* string, it'll be pretty hard to come up with rules on how to extract something out of it... is there any sort of structure?

Comment: the myApi keyword will always be displayed within the string.

Comment: Ah, that makes it solvable then :)

Comment: Just use a greedy regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the key, use a regular expression to match `myApi`, followed by any number of repeated groups of (a period followed by word characters). Then, you can just access the appropriate key on the object:

```js
const obj = {
  'myApi': ['keyOne', 'keyTwo'],
  'myApi.keyOne': ['three', 'four'],
  'myApi.keyOne.three': ['foobar']
};

function getVal(str) {
  const key = str.match(/myApi(?:\.\w+)*/)[0];
  console.log(obj[key]);
  return obj[key];
}
getVal("if(myApi.keyOne.three");
getVal("while(myApi.keyOne.three) {}");
getVal("if(myApi.keyOne) {}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Search for the key entry in the pattern:

```
var result = “”;
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    if (str.indexOf(key) !== -1 && key.length > result.length) result = key;
});

console.log(obj[result]);
```

Answer (score 1):

To make things more dynamic (even if there's no guarantee about `myApi`):

```js
function findStuff(str, obj) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  keys.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript
  const re = new RegExp(keys.map(key => key.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join('|'));
  const match = str.match(re);
  return match && match[0];
}

const obj = {
  'myApi': ['keyOne', 'keyTwo'],
  'myApi.keyOne': ['three', 'four'],
  'myApi.keyTwo': [""],
  'myApi.keyOne.three': ["THREE"],
  'myApi.keyOne.four': [""]
}

console.log(findStuff('while(myApi.keyOne.three) {}', obj));
```

We take all the keys from the object, then sort them by descending length (so the longest will be matched first). Then regexp-escape them and stick them together in a regexp alternation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression like

`myApi(\.\w+)*`

**Details**:

`myApi` - matches the `"myApi"` string

`(\.\w+)*` - matches **0 or more repetitions** of those alphanumeric strings which follows a period (`.`) character

```js
const obj = {
  'myApi': ['keyOne', 'keyTwo'],
  'myApi.keyOne': ['three', 'four'],
  'myApi.keyTwo': ['someVlaue1'],
  'myApi.keyOne.three': ['someVlaue2'],
  'myApi.keyOne.four': ['someVlaue3']
}

var str1 = 'while(myApi.keyOne.three) {}';
var str2 = 'if(myApi.keyOne) {}';

var regex = /myApi(\.\w+)*/g;

var val1 = obj[ str1.match(regex)[0] ];
var val2 = obj[ str2.match(regex)[0] ];

console.log(val1);
console.log(val2);
```